# How to find the size of text in dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have a data frame called df

it has values of Text

```
ID     Text
1      Hello, how are you?
2      What time is our meeting tomorrow?
3      It is going to rain soon.
4      nan          <----------- Empty record
5      She seems to like me.
```

how can I add a new column to the data frame with the size of its text

```
ID     Text                                      Size
1      Hello, how are you?                       19 
2      What time is our meeting tomorrow?        35
3      It is going to rain soon.                 26
4      nan          <----------- Empty record    0
5      She seems to like me.                     21
```

I tried this but it did not work

It was giving the size of the dataframe now for the text

```
df["Size"] = len(df["Text"])
```

Comment: `df["Text"].str.len()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html)

`df['Size'] = df['Text'].str.len()`

---

```
    ID  Text    Size
0   1   Hello, how are you? 19.0
1   2   What time is our meeting tomorrow?  34.0
2   3   It is going to rain soon.   25.0
3   4       
4   5   She seems to like me.   21.0
```

**Edit**:

```
df['Words'] = df['Text'].str.split(r'\s+')
df['Word_count'] = df['Words'].str.len()
```

---

```
    ID  Text    Size    Words   Word_count
0   1   Hello, how are you? 19.0    ['Hello,', 'how', 'are', 'you?']    4.0
1   2   What time is our meeting tomorrow?  34.0    ['What', 'time', 'is', 'our', 'meeting', 'tomorrow?']   6.0
2   3   It is going to rain soon.   25.0    ['It', 'is', 'going', 'to', 'rain', 'soon.']    6.0
3   4               
4   5   She seems to like me.   21.0    ['She', 'seems', 'to', 'like', 'me.']   5.0
```

Comment: Thanks tahat worked. but now i am trying to get the words count. I used this df.loc[:, 'Text_count']  = df["Text"].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
but I get error coz of the empty string. do u know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, this one you have the option to exclude the space and anything you dont want to be counted. Let me know if this helps.

```
test={'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Text':['Hello, how are you?', 'What time is our meeting tomorrow?', 'It is going to rain soon.',
                             'nan', 'She seems to like me.' ]}

df=pd.DataFrame(test)
df['body_len']= df['Text'].apply(lambda x: len(x)-x.count(" ")) # if you want to exclude the space
# df['body_len']= df['Text'].apply(lambda x: len(x)) #This count includes all the characters and the space.
df
```

output:

```
ID       Text                           body_len
1   Hello, how are you?                  16
2   What time is our meeting tomorrow?   29
3   It is going to rain soon.            20
4   nan                                   3
5   She seems to like me.                17
```

​